# OutOfMemoryException when saving image

Tags: c#, wcf, email, pdf, out-of-memory

I'm trying to send an email from my wcf service. Sending email works fine, but sending email with a pdf as attachment doesn't work at all. I get an OutOfMemoryException at `System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)`. The image is loaded from an url and included in the pdf.

I've read that OutOfMemoryException doesn't have to be that the application is running out of memory. But I have another almost identical wcf service on the same windows server that works fine. The only difference with that service is the address to the server. (It's located at a subdomain) and it uses another smtp address when sending emails.

Can the problem be because the IIS site or application pool is configurated wrong? And if so, how do I solve it?

Otherwise I have no idea why it's not working.

Any ideas? Please help.

Comment: Do you want to send a pdf file or an image?

Comment: What size has your PDF/image? Have you tried sending a 4*4px bitmap?

Comment: @reporter Ah, the pdf contains an image as a background. The problem is when genereting the pdf.

Comment: @Alexander, the size of the image is 280x128. So it's not a large image.

Comment: You can't convert PDF to image in this way!

Comment: Your problem definitely is not in the code you provided!

Comment: @Sarvesh. No i'm not trying to convert a pdf to a image. The pdf has a image

Comment: @user3082887 But you also can't get the background image from PDF in this way. Keep the image in a separate file and then attach image to email.

Comment: @Sarvesh I think you are misunderstanding me. I'm not trying to send a email with a image from a pdf. I'm including a pdf that has a image in it. And I get a error when generating the pdf. And it is working. Just not with this server. It works when I'm in debug mode on my local machine and on another server

Comment: @user3082887 Ok.. Can you show some more code?

Comment: An *an `OutOfMemoryException at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)`* most likely neither has to do with the PDF creation or the mail generation, merely with the image you are loading, the current memory load, and the allotted resources.